# Package Spring Boot app in a sidekick container

Tags: java, docker, microservices

Our ops team is pushing to deliver our Spring Boot microservices packaged in a sidekick (sometimes called sidecar) container, with Alpine.

The idea is to have a JRE container with a volume mapped to the sidekick. They claim that this would allow to easily swap the JRE version without repackaging the entire application and producing a new version.

I'm not in favor of this solution. Even though a change of JRE should not make a difference, I still have the feeling that this should be a major version change of our application. This being said, I would like to have other opinions.